# How do implement multi domain Identity server?

Tags: azure-active-directory, identityserver4, multi-tenant

I've a question!.. I need implement IdentityServer with N-tenant and its authentication provider(Azure AD all..).
For example:
Tenant1 ... AzureAD-1
Tenant2 ... AzureAD-2
Tenant3 ... AzureAD-3
(...)
TenantN ... Redirect AzureAD-N
Is possible it?
In addition, I need get information tenant from data base(it's clientId, client secret, callbackPath, etc..).
My first approach is:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
    (...)
        IEnumerable<AuthenticationSchema> schemas = repository.GetAuthenticationSchemas();
        
        if (schemas != null && schemas.Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach (AuthenticationSchema schema in schemas)
                builder.AddOpenIdConnect(schema.Id, options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = schema.Authority;
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters { ValidateIssuer = false };
                    options.ClientId = schema.ClientId;
                    options.ClientSecret = schema.ClientSecret;
                    options.CallbackPath = schema.CallBackPath;
                   
                });
        }
    (...)
    } 
}
```

this approach has problem that if i add a new openidconnect in database i need reset server bacause the registration is in startup application..

Is it possible do it dinamically?
Do they could help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can better solve the business need with multitenant application and here are some resources that would help you on multi tenant application.

1. [Authentication flows and application scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/authentication-flows-app-scenarios)
2. [Sign in any Azure Active Directory user using the multi-tenant application pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant)
3. [Code sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/master/2-WebApp-graph-user/2-3-Multi-Tenant/README.md)
4. [Recorded walkthrough](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B416AxHoMJ4)